# Setting Angular variable in HTML whilst using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if, ng-switch

I have the following code which works great:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">

      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"  style="width:  {{(p.availableIpAddressCount/p.totalIpAddressCount)*100|number:0}}%;background-color: #5cb85c">
        {{(p.availableIpAddressCount/p.totalIpAddressCount)*100|number:0}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

However, as you can see, I am repeating  `{{(p.availableIpAddressCount/p.totalIpAddressCount)*100|number:0}}` alot and I therefore would like to assign it to angular variable. I would also like to do an NG-switch on the result. This is what I have tried

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active" ng-init = "barPercentage= {{(p.availableIpAddressCount/p.totalIpAddressCount)*100|number:0}}">
<div ng-switch="barPercentage">
  <div ng-switch-when=">=0" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"  style="width: {{barPercentage}}%;background-color: #5cb85c">
    {{(p.availableIpAddressCount/p.totalIpAddressCount)*100|number:0}}
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

However this doesn't work at all but I'm unsure why. I get no errors in the console.

Any ideas?

Comment: what about just using ng-if

Comment: You don't need interpolation i.e. `ng-init = "barPercentage=(p.availableIpAddressCount/p.totalIpAddressCount)*100|number:0"`

Comment: @Satpal it still doesn't work without interpolation. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @MMK It doesn't make a difference,thanks.

Comment: @MattBoyl etry avoiding  `|number:0` inside ng-int and try excluding `{{}}` . working sample here https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29446/ . let me update if any issue

Comment: @supercool This half works thanks! The ng-switch still doesn't work in this instance.

Comment: inside switch statements we cannot use >,< condtions its used to match against the expression . you can simply use ng-if="value>=0" @MattBoyle . still u want persist with switch maybe a custom function at expression level should do it . hope you are clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);
DemoCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function DemoCtrl($scope) {
  // you can change this as you like. its just for demo purposes.
  $scope.p = {
    "availableIpAddressCount": 100,
    "totalIpAddressCount": 70
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="ui-bootstrap-tpls@*" data-semver="1.2.5" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
<script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.2" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.2" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="ui-bootstrap@1.3.2" data-semver="1.3.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
<!--using ng-if -->
  <div class="progress progress-striped active" ng-init="barPercentage= (p.availableIpAddressCount/p.totalIpAddressCount*100) | number:0">
  <div ng-if="barPercentage>=0" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: {{barPercentage | number: 0}}%;background-color: #5cb85c">
    {{barPercentage |number:0}}

  </div>
</div>

<!-- using ng-switch -->
  <div class="progress progress-striped active" ng-init="barPercentage= (p.availableIpAddressCount/p.totalIpAddressCount*100) | number:0">
  <div ng-switch on="(barPercentage>=0)">
    <div ng-switch-when="true">
    <div  class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: {{barPercentage | number: 0}}%;background-color: #5cb85c">
    {{barPercentage |number:0}}
  </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
      <!-- code to render the regular block -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MattBoyle Great.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest that you create a variable in your controller and expose it to the scope.

```
$scope.barPercentage = (p.availableIpAddressCount/p.totalIpAddressCount)*100 ;
```

The way to do it in your html is effectively `ng-init`, but it's [highly unrecommended in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Note that there are no AngularJS variables, rather a JavaScript object called `$scope` that is exposed to your template.